# sql server 2008 stored procedure, cannot use variable in single quote

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

here's my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchIngredients] 
    @Term NVARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.FoodAbbrev
    WHERE   Name LIKE '%@Term%'
    ORDER BY Name

END
```

I kept getting no result back. I think its because I put the varaible in the single quote and probably DB thinks that is part of string, not a variable.  tried a few other ways, still cannot fix it, please help me.

I also tried. still get nothing back.

```
    SET @Term = '''%' + @Term + '%'''

    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.FoodAbbrev
    WHERE   Name LIKE @Term
    ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply;

```
set @Term = '%' + @Term + '%'
```

Your just adding 2 constant strings to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is below:

```
set @FieldValue = '''' + @FieldValue + ''''
```